# how to change body background color from vue component and bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I made a little app with Vue.js, Laravel and Bootstrap 4. I am not a great front-end developer.
I created 3 states in the Vue data: 1 (enter the name), 2 (play the game) and 3 (results).
Every state should have a different background color but unfortunately I don't know how to do that. In the `welcome.blade.php` I set an image as background color of the body but unfortunately I cannot change that style in the component `Card.vue`.

**Card.vue**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="state === '1'" id="under_jumbo">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="text-success text-center display-3 font-weight-bold">BRISCOLAPP</h1>
            </div>
        </div >
        <div class="container h-100" >
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <form class="col-12">
                    <p class="text-center">Insert your name:</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pname" name="pname" maxlength="10">
                    <input type="button" value="Play the game">
                </form>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="state === '2'">
        <app-header :nav_comment="nav_comment" :remaining_cards="remaining_cards"></app-header>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-2">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_left_invisible}" id="pc_left" v-bind:rel="pc_left_rel">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_center_invisible}" id="pc_center" v-bind:rel="pc_center_rel">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_right_invisible}" id="pc_right" v-bind:rel="pc_right_rel">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-start pl-5">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pack_cards_invisible}" id="pack_cards" rel="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img v-bind:src="pc_game_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_game_invisible}" id="pc_game" v-bind:rel="pc_game_rel">
                <img v-bind:src="player_game_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_game_invisible}" id="player_game" v-bind:rel="player_game_rel">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-end pr-5">
                <img v-bind:src="game_briscola_src"  v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:game_briscola_invisible}" id="game_briscola" v-bind:rel="game_briscola_rel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-2">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_left_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_left_invisible}" id="player_left" v-bind:rel="player_left_rel">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_center_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_center_invisible}" id="player_center" v-bind:rel="player_center_rel">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_right_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_right_invisible}" id="player_right" v-bind:rel="player_right_rel">

        </div>
        <app-footer :remaining_cards="remaining_cards"></app-footer>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <p>viva</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Briscolapp</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url('images/poker-table.jpg');">
            <div id="app">
                <card></card>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src=" {{ asset('js/app.js') }} "></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#under_jumbo {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

By the way I should put the background color that is located in `style.css` to the body when the state is 1. Can help?

Comment: try this. hope this help you https://jsfiddle.net/Hafizu/og7n68xb/1/

Comment: @aslam is it possible even to change the body background color that is located outside the component as it is in the question?